# assign global variable in R function using tm: bug on linux?

Tags: linux, r, global-variables, tm

Using the package `tm` in R, I want to transform a corpus with a pretty complicated function, and I need some side effects for storing pertinent information. Since `content_transformer` requires a specific function format, the easy way is to use `<<-` in my function. The problem occurs with the code below:

```
library(tm)
a <- 4
n <- 2
corp<-VCorpus(VectorSource(rep("fish",n)))
(func<-content_transformer(
  function(x) {
    a <<- 42
    return(x)
}))
corp<-tm_map(corp,func)
print(a)
```

It prints the wrong answer, i.e. 4. But with n=1, it prints the right one. So I assume it is the multi-threading that tm does that fails to behave as scalar R. I guess it's a bug since on windows, it works. (Note: I use R 3.1.2 on linux and R 3.1.1 on windows).

Questions: is it a bug? if yes, a known bug? Is there an easy solution that does not require to refactor the code?

Thanks!

---

edit: additional example using assing

```
rm(list=ls())
library(tm)
env <- new.env()
a <- 1
n <- 2
corp<-VCorpus(VectorSource(rep("fish",n)))
(func<-content_transformer(
  function(x,e) {
    assign("a", 42, envir=e)
    print(e)
    print(ls.str(e))
    return(x)
}))
corp<-tm_map(corp,func,env)
print(env)
print(ls.str(env))
```

Comment: Dunno, but the vignette for `tm` doesn't explicitly say they support `<<-` for all cases.  Meanwhile, (I have never tried to use this package, so guessing) the volatility may well be handled differently.  Can you use `Pcorpus` instead?

Comment: Well, you have the same bug by actually creating a new.env and assigning things there so it's not just <<-. I never used PCorpus and don't know really what it is. I have to investigate.

Comment: On OSX, even with `n<-1`, I get no change in `a` in my global environment, so I suspect you're trying to do things that `tm` really is not set up to do.  My money is on there being several "layers" of environments, so the parent envir is not `.GlobalEnv`.

Comment: Try using `assign` to ensure you are going to the Global environment, if you are sure you must use globals. If `<<-` finds another `a` in any environment as it traverses its parents, it will change that instead.

Comment: @James I did that. it does not work either (cf. edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact this works accidentally under Windows because `mclapply` is not defined under windows and it is just a call to to an `lapply`.

Indeed, when you are calling `tm_map` , you are using this function :

```
tm:::tm_map.VCorpus
function (x, FUN, ..., lazy = FALSE) 
{
    if (lazy) {
        fun <- function(x) FUN(x, ...)
        if (is.null(x$lazy)) 
            x$lazy <- list(index = rep(TRUE, length(x)), maps = list(fun))
        else x$lazy$maps <- c(x$lazy$maps, list(fun))
    }
    else x$content <- mclapply(content(x), FUN, ...) ## this the important line
    x
}
```

So you can reproduce the "odd/normal" behavior by calling `mclapply`:

```
library(parallel)
res <- mclapply(1:2, function(x){a<<- 20;x})

a
[1] 4
```

a is unchanged and is still equal to 4. This is the normal paralel behavior since we avoid to have side effect. Under windows `mcapply` is  just a call to `lapply` so the value of the global variable is correctly changed.

#### pseudo solution

Here better to use `lapply` if you want to the global side effect, but you can emulate the global variable in a reading specially if you add `a` as a second argument your function...

```
func <- 
  function(x,a) {   
    a <- 42      ## use a here 
    x$a <- a     ## assign it to the x environment 
    return(x)    ## but the new value of a can not be used by others documents..
  }
(Func<-content_transformer(func))
res <- tm_map(corp,Func,a=4)
```

Comment: @agstudy I tried your "pseudo" solution. Am I right then that you access the variable with something like content(corp[[1]])[2]? Then it's a string. If I want to pass a matrix, it becomes tricky...